# Battling with wxpython

Tags: macos, wxpython, 32bit-64bit

I've spent a very frustrating evening trying to get `wxpython` to work on my MacBook Pro (running Snow Leopard 10.6.6). From reading the various threads on this topic both here and on other websites this is my understanding so far:

- If you are running python 2.6 or greater you can only work with wxpython if you access the 32-bit version
- Typing `python` at the command line prompt reveals that I am using `python 2.6.1`.
- Typing `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` so I'm using the default version installed with my OS. This means that typing the following at the command line prompt 
  `defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes` should change the version I'm using to the 32 bit version.
- With the above in place, I can now simply type the name of my python file (with the `wx` module imported) and my file will run successfully.

As you can no doubt guess however my file doesn't run successfully. I can't figure out what's going on, but maybe someone else can here are some other observations that might help...

typing `help()`, `modules` yields the following message and then prints out the modules, including `wx` and `wxpython`

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/pkgutil.py:110: DeprecationWarning: The wxPython compatibility package is no longer automatically generated or actively maintained.  Please switch to the wx package as soon as possible.`

`__import__(name)`

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/pkgutil.py:110: DeprecationWarning: twisted.flow is unmaintained.`

`__import__(name)`

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/twisted/python/filepath.py:12: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead`

`import sha`

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/twisted/words/im/__init__.py:8: UserWarning: twisted.im will be undergoing a rewrite at some point in the future.
  warnings.warn("twisted.im will be undergoing a rewrite at some point in the future.")`

`Fri Jun  3 22:23:48 Paul-Pattersons-MacBook-Pro.local python[3208] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.`

`_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.`

Then examining the `wx` module specifially yields...

`NAME`
    `wx`

`FILE`
    `/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.0/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/__init__.py`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have a Mac, but I read almost all the messages on the wxPython mailing list. As I understand it, you don't want to use the Python that came with your Mac. It has been modified for the Mac specifically somehow, so you should download a normal version of Python and install it.

As for the 32-bit question, with wxPython 2.8, you are correct. You are limited to 32-bit because of the Carbon API. However, if you scroll down the download page (http://wxpython.org/download.php) you will see that wxPython 2.9 has been released and it has a Cocoa build which (and I quote) "requires at least OSX 10.5, and supports either 32-bit or 64-bit architectures" and Python 2.7.

I highly recommend that you go and seek help on the wxPython mailing list. The author of wxPython is there and he uses a Mac and there are several other Mac addicts on the list too that answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: Okay, have posted over on wxpython mailing list.